# What is the supremum and infimum of given set?

Tags: real-analysis

I need to find the supremum and infimum of the set :

$S = \left[(-1)^n\left(4 - 1/n\right): n \in N\right]$

Calculating the few terms of sequence max S = $15/4$ ans min S = $-7/4$
Since both of these belong to the set they must be the supremum and infimum of the set.

Is my answer correct ?

Comment: Why would you think that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I notice that $(-1)^{100}(4 - \frac{1}{100}) = \frac{399}{100}$ is larger than $\frac{15}{4}$, so $\frac{15}{4}$ cannot be the max.

Furthermore, I notice that $(-1)^{1000000}(4 - \frac{1}{1000000}) = \frac{3999999}{1000000}$ is larger than $\frac{399}{100}$, so even $\frac{399}{100}$ cannot be the max.

If you can begin to see a pattern here, then perhaps you can formulate the correct guess as to the supremum of $S$. And then you can apply a similar analysis using odd powers of $-1$ to correctly guess the infimum.

Comment: Do you mean to say $4$ is a supremum of this sequence ?

Comment: Please can you  tell me whether I am right or wrong.

Comment: Yup, that's it.